# What are the advantages of Guava Stopwatch class?

Tags: java, time, guava, stopwatch, nanotime

In the Google Guava library, there is a `Stopwatch` class, and its [documentation](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Stopwatch.html) states this -

> An object that measures elapsed time in nanoseconds. It is useful to
>   measure elapsed time using this class instead of direct calls to
>   `System.nanoTime()` for a few reasons:
>
> 1. An alternate time source can be substituted, for testing or performance reasons.
> 2. As documented by `nanoTime`, the value returned has no absolute meaning, and can only be interpreted as relative to another timestamp
>      returned by nanoTime at a different time. `Stopwatch` is a more
>      effective abstraction because it exposes only these relative values,
>      not the absolute ones.

Question - What is this 'alternate time source' they refer to? And does JRE/JVM provide this option too?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

See the Stopwatch(Ticker) constructor. Supplying your own Ticker allows you to produce a Stopwatch that yields predictable results for testing purposes.

Comment: found some more info here - http://www.slideshare.net/tomaszdziurko/google-guava-almost-everything-you-need-to-know